# SQL table creation issue with , similar to, relation foreign key with primary key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

can anyone help me with this sql statment

```
Create table doctor(
  doctorId char(3),
  doctorName varchar(20),
  primary key (doctorId)
);
create table patient (
  patient_id char(4) not null check (patient_id LIKE 'P[0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
  doctorId char(3),
  patientName varchar(60) not null,
  dateOfBirth date not null,
  gender char(1),
  height decimal(4, 1) check (height > 0),
  weight decimal(4, 1) check(weight > 0),
  primary key (patient_id) FOREIGN KEY doctorId REFERENCES doctor(doctorId)
);
```

why 2nd table not created

Comment: You're missing a comma between the primary and foreign key constraints defined in the `patient` table.  You may tell us your version of SQL for more focused feedback.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and the pattern for the LIKE expression seems pretty dubious for standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

put these below code instead of your own code:

```
Create table doctor(
  doctorId char(3),
  doctorName varchar(20),
  primary key (doctorId)
);
create table patient (
  patient_id char(4) not null check (patient_id LIKE 'P[0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
  doctorId char(3),
  patientName varchar(60) not null,
  dateOfBirth date not null,
  gender char(1),
  height decimal(4, 1) check (height > 0),
  weight decimal(4, 1) check(weight > 0),
  primary key (patient_id) FOREIGN KEY doctorId REFERENCES doctor(doctorId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are missing a **,**

```
create table patient (
  patient_id char(4) not null check (patient_id LIKE 'P[0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
  doctorId char(3),
  patientName varchar(60) not null,
  dateOfBirth date not null,
  gender char(1),
  height decimal(4, 1) check (height > 0),
  weight decimal(4, 1) check(weight > 0),
  primary key (patient_id) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (doctorId) REFERENCES doctor(doctorId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that.

```
  Create table doctor(
  doctorId Int Identity(1,1), --It's 'Primary Key' so it should be Int or Guid
  doctorName varchar(20),
  CONSTRAINT pk_doctorId PRIMARY KEY (doctorId) --It's better!
);
  Create table patient (
  patient_id Int IDENTITY(1,1), --It's 'Primary Key' so it should be Int or Guid
  doctorId Int NOT NULL, --Every patient has a doctor, so it should be 'Not Null'
  patientName varchar(60) not null,
  dateOfBirth date not null,
  gender char(1),
  height decimal(4,1), -- I didnt see check operator, you should check > 0 in code.
  weight decimal(4,1),
  CONSTRAINT pk_patient_id PRIMARY KEY (patient_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_doctorId FOREIGN KEY (doctorId) REFERENCES doctor(doctorId)
);
```